# How do I create a SEO url for query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say my URL is `http://domain.com/category.php?id=2` to view all of articles in `cars` category.

My database structure `category table`

```
cat_id  cat_name
--------------------
1       books
2       cars
```

and `content table`

```
con_id  con_title                con_cat
----------------------------------------
1       How to be a picker           1 
2       How to repair your car       2 
3       How to sell your car easily  2
```

How do I change my current URL to be a SEO friendly? So it should be

```
http://domain.com/category/cars/
```

Then how to tell the query that's `/cars/` equal to `2` in `content table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually what is better is to use your HTTP server's  mod_rewrite  functionality.  And instead of saying /cars/  you'll say

```
   mysite.com/articles/How+to+repair+your+car/
```

which will be much more SEO friendly.

You'll need to [read a tutorial how mod_rewrite works](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) and the correct syntax, but in a nutshell you'll write a rule that takes whatever comes after /articles/ and converts it (on the server end) to something like

```
   category.php?title=How+to+repair+your+car
```

and you'll write some special PHP code to query a category that way.  This way your code is generic and when you add new categories, you won't have to change anything else, the new urls will work.  If you try to hard code a rule for each category, you're creating unneeded work.

Comment: Thanks Travis for the explanation. From current question URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133135/` will redirect to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133135/how-do-i-create-a-seo-url-for-query-string`. 

So from my current db structure I can change it to be something like this `http://domain.com/category/2/cars/`

Comment: Well in that case, you write a rule to take /category/ and send the number after it to your category.php?id= url

Just make sure you don't have any SQL Injection exploits, although you should be doing that anyway.  But I still insist you use the most verbose use possible, since everything after the /2/ is ignored.